# Why does this usage of until in Ruby not work, while another usage does?

Tags: ruby, block

The code below gives an error:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  until arr == arr.sort do
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      (arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]) if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
    end
  end 

  arr
end
```

(eval):433: (eval):433: compile error (SyntaxError)

(eval):426: syntax error, unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
                            ^

(eval):433: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end

But another variation of it below passes successfully. Why?

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  begin
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      (arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]) if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
    end
  end until arr == arr.sort

  arr
end
```

Comment: errors are some where else.. both is working for me

Comment: I'm using Codecademy's web interpreter...

Comment: You are learning it from there its good. besides install one ruby version and any editor. Practice in your personal machine as much as you can...

Comment: Did you really think this question is about bubble sort? It is not. It has nothing to do with bubble sort.

Comment: @sawa: No one mentioned anything about Bubble Sort.

Comment: @Borodin The OP tagged it as bubble sort. I see so many questions that are tagged for some word that appears in the question but is not at all crucial. I really wonder what these people are thinking.

Comment: I tagged it because that's how I tag anything, if there is a relation or not. If someone found this post with a bubble-sort tag, it would still be helpful because the code executes an actual bubble-sort. Tell me, how are tags done the "right" way?

Comment: @FivePoints You should tag only the portions that relate to the actual problem. Your method of tagging would work if you had eliminated all unnecessary minutiae by reducing it to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), but you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, this looks like a bug in `irb` on 1.8.7 (the version that labs.codecademy.com uses). Locally, when installing Ruby 1.8.7-p374 I see the same thing. However, if I run the code as a normal Ruby file, it works just fine.

However, Ruby 1.8.7 is [officially retired](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/), and it seems to me like the Codecademy Labs site is no longer maintained, either, so I recommend either learning Ruby with the "full" [Codecademy](http://codecademy.com) site, or installing a more recent version of Ruby (I recommend 2.0.0) locally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if you change the first code to the following it'll work out:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  total = (arr.count - 1)
  until arr == arr.sort do
    total.times do |i|
      (arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]) if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
    end
  end 

  arr
end
```

I've tested it with your [link](http://labs.codecademy.com/), so I'm guessing maybe it isn't properly configured, cause when I first added that `total` in `until`, it turned into an infinite loop. But someone has to check it against ruby, it maybe a bug.

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby, the `until` block doesn't use `do`, so you should do something like this:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  until arr == arr.sort
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      (arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]) if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
    end
  end 

  arr
end
```

**Edit**: Expanded the code so it includes the algorithm from the original question. This code works for me on `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`.