# Range loop works by itself, but not inside an until loop

Tags: ruby

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    sorted = false
    until sorted
        sorted = true
        (0...arr.length-2).each do |i|
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                sorted = false
            end
        end
    end
    arr
end

bubble_sort([4,6,2,8,1])
```

The following is the error message:

```
(eval):367: (eval):367: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):359: syntax error, unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND
        (0...arr.length-2).each do |i|
                                  ^
(eval):367: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
```

I don't understand why it is saying unexpected kEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [appears to be a bug in Ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764700/276949) - replacing `do/end` with `{}`:

```
    (0...arr.length-2).each do |i|
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
            arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
            sorted = false
        end
    end
```

and

```
    (0...arr.length-2).each { |i|
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
            arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
            sorted = false
        end
    }
```

fixes it.

Comment: I fixed that part of the code, but forgot to re-paste the error. Please see fixed error code, it is still giving me an error even with the each.

Comment: Your error must be somewhere above this code sample (check if you are properly closing a block/function above it). If you paste solely the code sample provided into a new file, it will work.

Comment: Also, what ruby version do you have? `ruby -v`

Comment: I was using http://repl.it/languages/Ruby. You're right, it does work on the ruby command prompt. Do you know why it would not work on that webpage?

Comment: Yes, that version of Ruby is 1.8.7. Try writing it with braces instead  like so: http://repl.it/UZW - This will work.

Comment: FYI, this appears to be a bug in Ruby 1.8.7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754479/why-does-this-usage-of-until-in-ruby-not-work-while-another-usage-does